# Spring Neo4J query abstract entity Attribute

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

I'm having trouble to grasp, use this correctly.

I have a **AbstractEntity/AbstractGraphEntity** class like this:

```
public abstract class GraphEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    @GraphId
    @Getter @Setter
    @JsonIgnore
    protected Long nodeId;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Index(unique = true, primary = true)
    protected String id;
}
```

And a **BaseGraphRepository** like this:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseGraphRepository<T extends GraphEntity> extends GraphRepository<T> {
    T findById(String id);
    Collection<T> findByIdIn(Collection<String> ids);
    T deleteById(String id);
    Collection<T> deleteByIdIn(Collection<String> ids);
}
```

The idea is to have multiple entities that are extenting GraphEntity, and use several repositories extending the BaseGraphRepository.

But each time I query on: findById, it keeps giving me null.

So I've tried using, `GraphEntity` as a `@NodeEntity`, but that's a terrible idea, since then if I do query for an ID of one kind of entity, let's say a Category, but on an ProductRepository, it will give me the `GraphEntity` object.

So how should I approach this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the findById/findByIdIn using the Neo4jRepository as such:

```
public interface BaseGraphRepository<T extends GraphEntity> extends Neo4jRepository<T, String> {}
```

But even with the Neo4jRepository the Generated Cypher for a custom query with the **GraphEntity** would be wrongly generated.

```
MATCH (n:GraphEntity) WHERE n.`id` ...
```

There might be some workaround to this, or it's a bad practice, I'm not sure.

Comment: The query generation is intended. This is because if it would not use `:GraphEntity`, then it would not be able to use the index which you declared in `class GraphEntity`. As a workaround, you could override the find methods to match `:GraphEntity:T`, but it is not very elegant.